# React hooks useState submit on second time from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have an orders management system - `Order.js page with Child Component ProductsForm.js`

- When filling the form to add product to order, I use `onChange` to update `useState` with the details
- When click submit - if didn't fill price, I update price from product information **and submit**
- 1st submit - it sends post request without price
- 2nd click on submit - it sends post request with the correct price

From reading I understand that it's something to add to the useState or convert it to useEffect?
Can I have multiple useEffect?

**How can I fix this issue?** - Thanks!

```
const submitOrderProduct = () => {

        if (subProductDetails.final_price === '')
            console.log('PRICE Not Set, Update Price from Product Info..')
            setSubProductDetails(subProductDetails => ({...subProductDetails,
                final_price: selectedItemDetails.final_price}))

     >>>>>>>>>>>>   HERE Need to Refresh / Callback Something  <<<<<<<<<<<<<

        const subProduct = {
            order: subProductDetails.order,
            product: subProductDetails.product,
            sub_product: subProductDetails.sub_product,
            units_to_buy: parseInt(subProductDetails.sub_units_to_buy),
            final_price: parseFloat(subProductDetails.final_price),
            unit_cost_before_fees: parseFloat(subProductDetails.unit_cost_before_fees),
            discount: parseInt(subProductDetails.sub_discount),
            notes: subProductDetails.sub_notes,
        }

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orderProducts/', subProduct)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to set state prior to the post request?

Would having the below expression fix your issue?

```
final_price: subProductDetails.final_price !== ""
             ? parseFloat(subProductDetails.final_price)
             : selectedItemDetails.final_price
```

You can then set state afterwards

```
setSubProductDetails(...subProductDetails, final_price: subProduct.final_price)
```

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the way to do that - thank you!